# free statistic website for analysing traffic

Tags: google-analytics, apache2, web-traffic

I am searching for a program like Google Analytics or Clicky which runs on my own servers. I have used awstats, which looks really old. It doesn't have to be open source but I would prefer something free.

If possible it should also analyse my Apache Logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to evaluate [Piwik](http://piwik.org/).

Comment: I've used Piwik before, and found it straightforward to setup and install. Think of it as a simpler, self-hosted Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/).

Answer (score 0):

Log analyzers have mostly fallen out of favor of the nifty javascript client-side things.

Anyway, there's a list here:

http://counterguide.com/listing/logs.dir.html

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/).  It's always enabled by default on my Fedora linux installs, and it does all the analysis I need.  I suspect it's very simple to set up on its own, too.